# Django duplicate migrations in apps

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

Django keeps making duplicate migrations in for my application. I've ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` before I changed my model. After the changes I ran `makemigrations` again to make migrations for the updated model, I got the following error:

```
CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected; multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph: (0001_initial, 0001_initial 3 in sessions; 0002_remove_content_type_name 3, 0002_remove_content_type_name, 0001_initial 3 in contenttypes; 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length 3, 0010_alter_group_name_max_length 3, 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages 3, 0006_require_contenttypes_0002 3, 0005_alter_user_last_login_null 3, 0001_initial 3, 0008_alter_user_username_max_length 3, 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length 3, 0011_update_proxy_permissions, 0011_update_proxy_permissions 3, 0004_alter_user_username_opts 3, 0003_alter_user_email_max_length 3 in auth; 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices 3, 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add 3, 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices, 0001_initial 3 in admin).
```

To fix them run 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge'

Running `makemigrations --merge` doesn't work: `ValueError: Could not find common ancestor of {'0002_remove_content_type_name', '0002_remove_content_type_name 3', '0001_initial 3'}`

There are many duplicate migrations in apps that I haven't touched (auth, admin, etc.):

```
admin
 [ ] 0001_initial 3
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add 3
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
 [ ] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices 3
auth
 [ ] 0001_initial 3
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length 3
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [ ] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length 3
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [ ] 0004_alter_user_username_opts 3
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null 3
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [ ] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002 3
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [ ] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages 3
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [ ] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length 3
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [ ] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length 3
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [ ] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length 3
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [ ] 0011_update_proxy_permissions 3
contenttypes
 [ ] 0001_initial 3
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
 [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name 3
database
 (no migrations)
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0001_initial 3
```

The only app that, as far as I know, should've been affected is `database`. Why is Django making these duplicate migrations? Is there any way I can get rid of these? Or apply them so they are not blocking anymore? How I can make sure this doesn't happen again?

Comment: Django doesn't "make duplicate migrations", and it certainly doesn't use whitespaces in migrations files names, so the cause of the problem is on your side. Given the symptom and the file names, I stronly suspect those are really plain duplicated files - which you can easily check by yourself by comparing those files contents, isn't it ? If so, the cure is simple: just remove those duplicate files...

Comment: I was thinking already that the format was strange. I want to remove the migrations, but I don't know where they live. I have a `virtualenv` setup.

Comment: I found them, they live in my env. I guess I can just remove it and make a new environment in order to reset the whole thing.

Comment: You can just directly remove the files from your env - it's a local copy, you can do whatever you want with it. Or uninstall / reinstall Django from your env.

Comment: Thanks. Still don't know where the copies came from, but it's fixed now, will close the question.

Comment: Well, it would indeed be interesting to know where those files came from to prevent the issue to happen again, but chances are this was a non-reproducible accident....

Comment: OMFG, I had the exactly same problem. I don't know why I had duplicate migrations too. I think it's a bug from Django as the error seems pretty new in SO. You saved my life guys !

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, if you have the option, the easiest and fastest way is...

- Delete migration files.
- Delete entire database.
- run "python manage.py makemigrations" again
- run "python manage.py migrate" again

or... if you have a db in production with data and you can't reset:

- Check last production version
- Delete migration files (until this version).
- Delete entire local(sqlite) database.
- run "python manage.py makemigrations" again
- run "python manage.py migrate" again

Important... copy /migrations/ folder somewhere to recover files if necessary.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but how do I remove the migrations for apps like `auth` and `session`? They live in my environment somewhere?

Comment: remove environment: rmvirtualenv.... and then re-create it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the duplicates weren't created by Django but by some other process. Completely removing my environment and reinstalling all dependencies helped. Removing the migrations also would've worked.